# How does react redux dependencies work with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, reducers

I have written a code to manage users profile with JWT , I have used useState to manage the form inputs and working with redux to manage the data. The inputs are not being updated with the data we are receiving from api/action

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {getUser , updateUser} from '../actions/userActions'
import '../css/profile.css'
import {listMyOrders} from '../actions/orderActions'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Profile = ({history}) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [name , setName] = useState('');
    const [email , setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password , setPassword] = useState('');
    const [confirmPassword , setConfirmPassword] = useState('');

    const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);

    
    const userProfile = useSelector((state) => state.userProfile);
    const {userData , loading , error} = userProfile;

    const myOrders = useSelector(state => state.orderListMy);
    const {orders , loading:loadingOrders} = myOrders;

    useEffect(
        async () => {
            if (!userLogin.userData) {
                history.push('/login')
            } else {
                if (!userData || !userData.name) {
                    dispatch(getUser());
                    dispatch(listMyOrders());
                }
                if(!myOrders.order){
                    dispatch(listMyOrders());
                }
                else {
                    setName(userData.name);
                    setEmail(userData.email);
                }
            }
            }
        , [dispatch, history , userData , userLogin.userData]);

        const handleUpdate = () => {
            if(password == confirmPassword) {
                dispatch(updateUser( userData._id , loading , name , email , password));
            }
        }


    return (
        <section id="profile">
            <div className="inside">
                <div className="user-profile">
                <p className="title">User Profile</p>
                <div className="msg-container">
                </div>
                <div className="name-container">
                    <label className="name-label">Name</label>
                    <input type="name" onLoad={ (e) =>
                        setTimeout(console.log('hello') , 1000)
                    } onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} value={name} placeholder="Your Name" htmlFor="name" />
                </div>
                <div className="email-container">
                    <label className="email-label">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="email address" htmlFor="email" />
                </div>
                <div className="password-container">
                    <label className="password-label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" htmlFor="password" />
                </div>
                <div className="password-container">
                    <label className="password-label">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" htmlFor="password" />
                </div>
                <button onClick={handleUpdate} className="submit">Update</button>
                </div>
                <div className="my-orders">
                <div className="title">My Orders</div>
                    <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>DATE</td>
                        <td>TOTAL</td>
                        <td>PAID</td>
                        <td>DELIVERED</td>
                        <td />
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {!loadingOrders && orders.map(order => (
                        <tr key={order._id}>
                        <td>{order._id}</td>
                        <td>{order.createdAt.substring(0, 10)}</td>
                        <td>{order.totalPrice}</td>
                        <td>{order.isPaid ? (
                      order.paidAt.substring(0, 10)
                    ) : (
                      <i className='fas fa-times' style={{ color: 'red' }}></i>
                    )}</td>
                        <td>{order.isDelivered ? (
                      order.deliveredAt.substring(0, 10)
                    ) : (
                      <i className='fas fa-times' style={{ color: 'red' }}></i>
                    )}</td>
                        <td><Link to={`/order/${order._id}`}><button className="details">Details</button></Link></td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

    )
}

export default Profile
```

here are the code for reducers and actions I have written

```html
//reducer
//state - userProfile
export const userGetProfileReducer = (state = {userData : {}} , action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case USER_GET_REQUEST :
            return { loading : true , state};
        case USER_GET_SUCCESS :
            return ({ loading : false , userData : action.payload });
        case USER_GET_ERROR : 
            return ({ loading : false , error : action.payload });
        default : 
            return state;
    }
}
```

```html
//action - getUser
export const getUser = () => async(dispatch , getState) => {

    dispatch({type : USER_GET_REQUEST , loading : true })

    const headers = {headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'AUTHORIZATION' : `Bearer ${getState().userLogin.userData.token}`
    }}
    

    try {
        const {data} = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/users/profile', headers);
        dispatch({type : USER_GET_SUCCESS , payload : data , loading : false});

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        dispatch({type : USER_GET_ERROR , loading : false , payload: error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message})
    }
}
```

Note - Orders functionality is working perfectly fine. Inputs fields are not being updated with response data. I am sure I have messed up with useEffect dependencies. It would be good if someone can help me......

Comment: Did connect to the redux store ? https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Comment: What do the redux devtools say? What actions are dispatched, what data do they have and how do they change the state? Then you can put some relevant information in your question like: following action is dispatched and state changed

Comment: The data is being called and stored successfully in the store reducer. I believe everything's fine except the initial state of the reducer and the dependencies of the useEffect hook